# Google api php client

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement the google analytics API on localhost site using xampp on Mac OS.

but Im getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See the instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ga-api/google-api-php-client/autoload.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ga-api/index.php(4): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ga-api/google-api-php-client/autoload.php on line 14

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: yes, via Terminal http://take.ms/Ey1SZ

Comment: Can you try `composer dump-autoload` to update the autoloader?

Comment: I got "Generating autoload files"

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I installed the google api php client on /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/ga-api/ is this ok?

Comment: I think that's not ok. I would move ga-api to some directly inside of my project say `lib`. I'll then require it where I want to create the client https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#basic-example

Comment: @OluwafemiSule this is my folders structure http://take.ms/PkGqL "/ga-api/" is where I reach the site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145349/discussion-between-mosh-and-oluwafemi-sule).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you installed the library using Composer, it will be installed to `vendor` and will be available in the `autoload.php` that Composer generates.

I will `require_once DIR. '/vendor/autoload.php';` in `index.php` (preferred) or where I need to instantiate the `GoogleClient` class.

Ensure that the path to client credentials are rightly referenced when you set auth config like so:
`Google_Client->setAuthConfig($pathToCredentials)`

Reference:

- Setting auth credentials: 
  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-oauth
- Autoloading classes:
  https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading